# PGFPlots how can I hide extra y tick marks?

Tags: pgfplots

simple question (I hope)

Using pgfplots 1.5.1, miktex 2.9 on Windows 7 32 bits.   I'd like to hide the tick marks at the right and top side of the plot, but without losing the lines (e.g. keep the plot axis style as box but only keep tick marks in the left y axis and bottom x axis, keeping the  lines in the upper x axis (without tick marks nor labels) and right y axis (without tick marks nor labels)

If i use `ytick=\empty` it removes all of the labels and ticks, but I don't want that, I just want the extra y and x ticks  removed.

So far I've tried:

```
every extra y tick = \empty,
every extra y tick/.style={\empty},
extra y ticks={},
extra ytick =\empty, 
hide extra y ticks,
extra y tick style={tickwidth=0cm,major tick length=0cm},
```

But no luck,

Any help is much appreciated.

Best regards,

(edit: Forgot to add I'm using Latex->PDF profile)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The position of the tick marks is set using the key `tick pos=<left|right|both>` for the x and y axis simultaneously, and `xtick pos` and `ytick pos` to set the tick marks separately. In your case, you want to set `ytick pos=left`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ytick pos=left]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `extra y tick` options refer to something different: You can manually add additional tick positions, "extra ticks", to highlight certain positions. You specify where to add new tick positions using `extra y ticks={<list>}`, and set the styles for these extra ticks using `extra y tick style=<options>`. Here's an example, highlighting the y position 0.5, which ordinarily doesn't get a tick mark:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ytick pos=left,
    extra y ticks={0.5},
    extra y tick style={red, yticklabel pos=right,ytick pos=right}]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant as always Jake, thank you very much.

Comment: As an addition, now that Jake has pointed the answer, looking it up in the manual shows that this is on section 4.14.2 Tick Alignment: Positions and Shifts, first paragraph.

Comment: @JoseR Thanks for the reference to the manual. But for questions that someone has already asked, this site is so much faster ...

Comment: @Jake If you have a `ylabel` set, and the `extra y ticks` are wide, then the `ylabel` gets offset to the left—presumably because the calculations are taking into account the width of the labels as if they were on the left. Do you know how to fix this?