# Pgfplots Tick Position

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43449/pgfplots-how-can-i-hide-extra-y-tick-marks#43452), I want to hide some ticks in a pgfplots axis. However, I'm trying to manipulate a 3D plot. I used the proposed answer and reread the documentation at:
"4.15.2  Tick Alignment: Positions and Shifts"
but didnt get the desired (expected result). Ideally I want ticks and labels in the front (x), left (z) and right (y) and no Ticks and no labels on all other box-lines.
This is what I get:

[image]

however, what I'd expect is, that `ytick pos = left` hides the (picture side) left ticks and `ztick pos = left` hides the bottom back side and top left side ticks.

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      width=5cm,
      height=5cm,
      scale only axis,
      plot box ratio=3 2 1,
      xmin=-1.5,
      xmax=1.5,
      ymin=-1,
      ymax=1,
      zmin=-0.5,
      zmax=0.5,
      xtick pos = left,
      ytick pos = left,
      ztick pos = left,
      %tick pos = left,
      view={40}{20},
    ]
    \addplot3[domain=0:2*pi,samples=50,samples y=0]
      ({sin(deg(x))},
      {cos(deg(x))},
      {x/(2.5*pi)-0.5});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you put a complete MWE.

Comment: [I'm afraid you are out of luck](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185442/changing-the-3d-tick-style-of-pgfplots). Consequently, I'm afraid this is a duplicate. Please alert me if that post doesn't answer your question.